# How to convert Float Result into String and save it into Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

My application has one features to calculate the BMI based on height and weight. The result for the BMI is in float. How do i convert float value to string to save the result into firebase and retreive it later. Because as far as i know firebase database cannot save result that in float value. Can i use parseString? how to code it. thank you in advance.

```
public void bmiCalculator(View v) {
            String heightStr = height.getText().toString();
            String weightStr = weight.getText().toString();

            if (heightStr != null && !"".equals(heightStr)
                    && weightStr != null && !"".equals(weightStr)) {
                float heightValue = Float.parseFloat(heightStr) / 100;
                float weightValue = Float.parseFloat(weightStr);

                float bmi = weightValue / (heightValue * heightValue);


            }
        }

        private void displayBMI(float bmi) {
            String bmiLabel = "";

            if (Float.compare(bmi, 15f) <= 0) {
                bmiLabel = getString(R.string.very_severely_underweight);
            } else if (Float.compare(bmi, 15f) > 0 && Float.compare(bmi, 16f) <= 0) {
                bmiLabel = getString(R.string.severely_underweight);
            } else if (Float.compare(bmi, 16f) > 0 && Float.compare(bmi, 18.5f) <= 0) {
                bmiLabel = getString(R.string.underweight);
            } else if (Float.compare(bmi, 18.5f) > 0 && Float.compare(bmi, 25f) <= 0) {
                bmiLabel = getString(R.string.normal);
            } else if (Float.compare(bmi, 25f) > 0 && Float.compare(bmi, 30f) <= 0) {
                bmiLabel = getString(R.string.overweight);
            } else if (Float.compare(bmi, 30f) > 0 && Float.compare(bmi, 35f) <= 0) {
                bmiLabel = getString(R.string.obese_class_i);
            } else if (Float.compare(bmi, 35f) > 0 && Float.compare(bmi, 40f) <= 0) {
                bmiLabel = getString(R.string.obese_class_ii);
            } else {
                bmiLabel = getString(R.string.obese_class_iii);
            }

            bmiLabel = bmi + "\n\n" + bmiLabel;
            result.setText(bmiLabel);


        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...as far as i know firebase database cannot save result that in float value.

Firebase can store any valid JavaScript number value, which covers much more than the likely range of BMI values. So if you want, you can just store the float values in the database directly.

But if you want to convert a `float` to a string, use:

```
String.valueOf(23.42) // returns "23.42"
```

And if you want to convert a string containing a number back to a `float`, use:

```
Float.parseFloat("23.42") // returns 23.42
```

Comment: Sir, how can i save that float result directly into database?

Comment: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/khalid/bmi").setValue(23.42)`

Comment: It's just a random value. If you have a variable with the right float value, put that in there.